# java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException and java.io.EOFException when trying to build Jenkins Plugin from source

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to build [Cucumber Test Result Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cucumber+Test+Result+Plugin) (0.8.2) and I am receiving the following error after `mvn package`:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/chrisandrew/sources/cucumber-testresult-plugin/target/classes/META-INF/exposed.stapler-beans
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.527s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 20 17:33:31 BST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/92M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5:compile (default-compile) on project cucumber-testresult-plugin: Compilation failure
[ERROR] error: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/chrisandrew/sources/cucumber-testresult-plugin/target/classes/META-INF/exposed.stapler-beans
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5:compile (default-compile) on project cucumber-testresult-plugin: Compilation failure
error: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/chrisandrew/sources/cucumber-testresult-plugin/target/classes/META-INF/exposed.stapler-beans

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:504)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
error: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/chrisandrew/sources/cucumber-testresult-plugin/target/classes/META-INF/exposed.stapler-beans

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:729)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I tried "resolving" these errors by creating two empty files *target/classes/META-INF/exposed.stapler-beans* and *target/classes/META-INF/annotations/hudson.Extension* (don't know if I should have done this, probably not...) and now I get this:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error: java.io.EOFException
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.443s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 20 16:48:45 BST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/91M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5:compile (default-compile) on project cucumber-testresult-plugin: Compilation failure
[ERROR] error: java.io.EOFException
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5:compile (default-compile) on project cucumber-testresult-plugin: Compilation failure
error: java.io.EOFException

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:504)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
error: java.io.EOFException

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:729)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

`mvn -v` output:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T08:57:37-03:00)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.9.0-ea, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.19.0-25-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the Jenkins plugin you are trying to build? What is the original error?

Comment: I added more details to the question, as you asked

Comment: I just checked out `cucumber-testresult-plugin` version 0.8.2 and I was able to compile it successfully. Running Maven 3.3.3 on Windows. Try launching `mvn clean package`.

Comment: Same Maven version here. I've just installed Maven from binary and checked out this source from repo. Is there anything else required? I have no previous experience with building plugins from Jenkins. This is my first try and this error message doesn't seems very helpful... Maybe a missed some step?

Comment: Aha! After `mvn clean`, I am able to build the plugin using `mvn hpi:hpi`. Strangely, `mvn package` or `mvn install` continues to give me the same errors.

Comment: Even `mvn hpi:hpi` working, the resulting hpi fails to load in Jenkins...

Answer (score 5):

Got the same error with java-9, compiled successfully using oracle jdk 1.8

Comment: I wonder what caused this. Somehow I don't think is normal even with Java 9.

Comment: What make the situation worse is that mvn would not use the java version from PATH and you may have to define JAVA_HOME to point to Java 8 in order to convince it to use older java.

Comment: This seems to work for me: `export JAVA_HOME=\`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8\`` (on macOS)